# How to read a text char by char and line by line on c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

its me again with this project. im having a problem reading the text on my input cause the program never ends. The problem its here [full description of the problem](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=1130)
but i dont know how to read the text char by char , and then read the next line the same way.

```
    freopen("input.txt","rt",stdin);
freopen("output.txt","wt",stdout);

int n=-1;
int m=-1;
int cont =0;
int VMatriz[100][100]={0};
int Mapa[100][100]={0};
while(n!=0 && m!=0)
{
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);

    if (n==0 && m==0)
        break;
    cont++;
    printf("Field # %d",cont);


    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   printf("/n");
        for (int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            //scanf("%d ",&Mapa[i][j]);
            Mapa[i][j]=getchar();

            if (Mapa[i][j]=='*')
                {
                    if (j-1>=0)
                        VMatriz[i][j-1]++;
                    if (j+1<m)
                        VMatriz[i][j+1]++;
                    if (i-1>=0)
                        VMatriz[i-1][j]++;
                    if (i+1<m)
                        VMatriz[i+1][j]++;

                    if (j-1>=0 && i-1>0)
                        VMatriz[i-1][j-1]++;
                    if (j-1>=0 && i+1<m)
                        VMatriz[i+1][j-1]++;
                    if (j+1<m && i-1>0)
                        VMatriz[i-1][j+1]++;
                    if (j+1<m && i+1<m)
                        VMatriz[i+1][j+1]++;

                    VMatriz[i][j]='*';

                printf("%d",VMatriz[i][j]);


                }

        }   

    }
    printf("/n");


}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make the logic simple

1. Read Line by line till you reach the EOF
2. Parse the line for each char

You can use [CStdioFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a499td6y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
CStdioFile file (_T("File.txt"), CStdioFile::modeRead);
CString buffer;

while (file.ReadString(buffer))
{
   CString strLine = buffer;
   //Parse the strLine for each character
}
```

Comment: How do you know that he can use the MFC? And that he is coding on Windows?